# Joining and Updating PostGIS data using QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have a PostGIS database with which I am currently using QGIS to manage the layers. Say I have a layer in PostGIS that I want to do a join to to add new data in. Is it possible to do this join **in-situ** without having to download the layer locally, do the join and re-upload the layer, overwriting the previous one?

If this isn't possible, is the best alternative to write a script to handle the downloading, joining and re-uploading all together?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be best practice but I have found that the easiest option in my case is to just create a new field that mimics the joined fields. This avoids having to create a whole new layer which needs to be saved and re-uploaded.

Hopefully using this it will then be easier to create a script to automate the join and duplicating the fields.